# Cannot convert value of type 'SecCertificate' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>!'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlsession, unsafe-pointers

I am trying to perform https request but when I try to match local and remote ssl certificates Xcode shown me above error. I have attached an image of error also code below, any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

[image]

Below is the complete delegate method of `URLSessionDelegate`.

```
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == (NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {


        let serverTrust:SecTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
        let certificate: SecCertificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0)!
        let remoteCertificateData = CFBridgingRetain(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate))!
        let cerPath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "xxxxx", ofType: "der")!
        let localCertificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile:cerPath)!
        print(localCertificateData.length)
        let result  = remoteCertificateData.isEqual(localCertificateData as Data)
        let certDataRef = localCertificateData as! CFData
        var cert: SecCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certDataRef)!
        let certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(nil, cert, 1, nil)
        SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, certArrayRef)

        SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(serverTrust, false)
        print(result)
        var trustResult: SecTrustResultType = SecTrustResultType.invalid
        SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult)
        if (trustResult == SecTrustResultType.unspecified ||
            trustResult == SecTrustResultType.proceed)
        {
            let credential:URLCredential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust)
            challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
            completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))

        } else {

            completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
    }
    else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate
    {
        let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "client", ofType: "p12")!
        let PKCS12Data = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!
        let identityAndTrust:IdentityAndTrust = self.extractIdentity(certData: PKCS12Data);
        let urlCredential:URLCredential = URLCredential(
            identity: identityAndTrust.identityRef,
            certificates: identityAndTrust.certArray as? [AnyObject],
            persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession);
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, urlCredential);
    }
    else
    {
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line causing the error, is for creating a `CFArray`.

One simple way to create a `CFArray`, is to use bridging the Swift `Array` to `CFArray`.

Try changing the line:

```
let certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(nil, cert, 1, nil)
```

To:

```
let certArrayRef = [cert] as CFArray
```